# Problem with modulo in field

Tags: field-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have problem with comprehending how works number in field when it's rasied to negative power.

For instance if we have $4^{-1}$ at $Z_{5}$ I tried to write it as $4\cdot 4^{-1}+4^{-1}=4^{-1}(1+4)$ so it's $4^{-1}= 0 \space mod \space5 $ ??

Comment: you proved that $1+4^{-1}\equiv0$ mod $5$ hence $4^{-1}\equiv-1$ mod $5$

Comment: I don't see it can you show yours approach ?

Comment: You can't divide by $0$ mod $5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $4.4^{-1}\equiv1$ mod $5$ so $4.4^{-1}+4^{-1}\equiv1+4^{-1}$
mod $5$.

Also $4.4^{-1}+4^{-1}\equiv\left(4+1\right)4^{-1}\equiv0$
mod $5$

Proved is now $1+4^{-1}\equiv0$ mod $5$ or equivalently $4^{-1}\equiv-1$
mod $5$ or equivalently $4^{-1}\equiv4$ mod $5$

---

To 'find' $4^{-1}$ in situations like this just go on search for the unique element $r\in\mathbb Z_5$ that satisfies $r\times 4\equiv1$ mod $5$.

Comment: ok thanks but I have one more question If we have $5^{-1}$ mod $7$ in $F_{7}$ then analogically $5^{-1}(5+1)=1+5^{-1}$ mod $7$ how to finish this ?

Comment: This is not the route you should take. If $r$ denotes $5^{-1}$ then $r\times5\equiv 1$ mod $7$. In your comment you have stated that $r\times6\equiv 1+r$ mod $7$... This gives no essential profit. As I said in my answer: you can find out by checking the elements one by one. There are not many and soon you find that $5\times3\equiv1$ mod $7$. So $5^{-1}=3$ here.

Comment: OK, so the unique element to $5^{-1}$ is $5$ so $5^{-1} \cdot 5 = 1$ mod $7$ but I don't know what to do next

Comment: As said try out: $7|5\times 1-1$? No! $7|5\times 2-1$? No! $7|5\times 3-1$? Yes! Ready: $5^{-1}\equiv3$ mod $7$.

Comment: OK I finally get it. Thank you very much!